# Permitir longitud cero en Postgresql + NOT NULL

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, null, required

¿Hay algo parecido al permitir longitud cero + requerido (not null) de Access en Postgesql?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si. Puedes definir el campo como `NOT NULL` y el valor por `default` como longitud cero.

```
CREATE TABLE public.mitabla
(
   id serial, 
   nombre character varying(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```